# MySQL stored procedure insert validation

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, database-design

I have two tables `acceptances` and `turnovers`. Let's just assume that these tables both have the columns `id`, and `date` only.

I need to be able to insert same dates across the 2 tables only up to 4 times.

For example: 5 users are trying to create a booking schedule.

- 3 of the 5 users create an acceptance schedule.
- 2 of the 5 users create a turnover schedule.

1 of these inserts should be rejected even in race conditions.

I have the following stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE acceptanceDateEntryCount int;
    DECLARE turnoverDateEntryCount int;

    SELECT COUNT(date) FROM acceptances WHERE DATE(date) = DATE(insertDate) INTO acceptanceDateEntryCount;
    SELECT COUNT(date) FROM turnovers WHERE DATE(date) = DATE(insertDate) INTO turnoverDateEntryCount;

    IF((acceptanceDateEntryCount + turnoverDateEntryCount) < 4) THEN
        INSERT INTO acceptances (date) VALUES (insertDate);
    ELSE
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE
            '45030'
        SET
            MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot create acceptance schedule. Max limit of 4 same date entries are found in acceptances table and turnovers table',
            MYSQL_ERRNO = '45030';
    END IF;
END
```

NOTE: This stored procedure is for creating an acceptance booking only. But there is another stored procedure which is just the same, but inserts into the turnovers table.

Is this stored procedure enough to make sure that even in race conditions where a lot of users try to create a booking schedule, if entries of the same date exists, the insert will be rejected if it has the same date.

Or should I just scrap this and use pessimistic locking to make sure that inserts on these tables do not run concurrently?

Answer (score 0):

Tack `FOR UPDATE` on the end of each `SELECT` statement.

Also include

```
START TRANSACTION;
```

and

```
COMMIT;
```